# Can JDK 11 update automatically?

Tags: java, java-11

There is no Java Control Panel with JDK 11, and it seems to remove the auto update as well. So how could I update JDK? Will it push the updating notification?

Comment: I don't recall the JDK distributions *ever* automatically updating...I recall that being a thing for the JRE and its associated Java Web Plugin, but it's been years since anyone's bothered with that...

Comment: You will likely just have to download new versions manually. I assume you’re using OpenJDK builds?

Comment: Oracle removed Java Update in JRE 11 ([Java 11 changelog](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8185077))

Comment: @Snowy_1803, would you mind adding that as proper answer?

Comment: There is a currently open AdoptOpenJDK issue for this feature: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-installer/issues/4

Answer (score 2):

Oracle removed Java Update in JRE 11 ([Java 11 changelog](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8185077)). You have to manually update from Oracle’s or OpenJDK’s website when a new version is available.